# UDP Sending multiple splitted strings

Tags: java, udp, stringbuilder, datagram

Im having a problem that i can't solve by my own. I think my approach with splitting and adding to a array list and reassembling the message pieces in the end works great if (1) the MSG > BUFFER & message rate is 1msg/second. But the problems appear when i send more than 1 message/second and i have to split a large/small message. Yes the approach may be inefficient in the long run, but this is an assignment so i just want to get it working as i wanted and i'm fine by that.

I am pretty sure the problem is that it of course send every message pieces rate times. And the output is like this in my console:

```
--------------------------------
| UDP Echo Client
| Configuration: 
| server name: localhost
| port: 4950
| buffer: 8
| rate: 5
| message size: 15
--------------------------------
Original: [HelloHe, lloHell, o]
Received: [HelloHe]
MESSAGE IS NOT EQUAL!
Received: [HelloHe, HelloHe]
MESSAGE IS NOT EQUAL!
Received: [HelloHe, HelloHe, HelloHe]
MESSAGE IS NOT EQUAL!
```

Can anyone please try to help me ? What is the best way to fix this ?

UDP Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

/*
UDP Echo client. Sends a echo message of a size to the server and gets it back.
It checks so that the message wasn't lost or anything has happened to it.
by jv222dp

Rate works perfectly when MSG.length <= MY_BUFFER.
When the BUFFER is smaller then the MSG it works great if rate is 1
 */
public class UDPEchoClient {

    private static final String MSG = "HelloHelloHello";

    private static int MY_PORT;
    private static int RATE;
    private static int MY_BUFFER;
    private static String HOST_NAME;
    private static byte[] buf;
    private static int packages;
    private static int chars;
    private static List<String> originalMsg;
    private static List<String> receivedString = new ArrayList<>(packages);
    private static DatagramPacket sendPacket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (!isCorrect(args)) {
            System.exit(1);
        } else {

            try {

            /* Configuration printout */
                System.out.println("--------------------------------" +
                        "\n| UDP Echo Client" +
                        "\n| Configuration: " +
                        "\n| server name: " + HOST_NAME +
                        "\n| port: " + MY_PORT +
                        "\n| buffer: " + MY_BUFFER +
                        "\n| rate: " + RATE +
                        "\n| message size: "+MSG.length()+
                        "\n--------------------------------");
                /* Sets the buffer */
                buf = new byte[MY_BUFFER];

                /* Create socket */
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);

                /* Create local endpoint using bind() */
                SocketAddress localBindPoint = new InetSocketAddress(0);
                socket.bind(localBindPoint);

                socket.setSoTimeout(2000);

                /* Create remote endpoint */
                SocketAddress remoteBindPoint = new InetSocketAddress(HOST_NAME,
                        (MY_PORT));



                /* Sends and reads the echo message */
                sendEchoPackets(socket, remoteBindPoint);


            } catch (SocketException se) {
                System.err.println("Host unreachable!" +
                        "Wrong port or host offline");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sendEchoPackets(DatagramSocket socket, SocketAddress remoteBindPoint) {

        System.out.println("Original: "+originalMsg.toString());

        /* For each string in the List of message parts */
        for (String message : originalMsg) {

        /* Create datagram packet for sending message */
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                    message.getBytes(),
                    message.length(),
                    remoteBindPoint);

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask rate = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        if (RATE == 0 || RATE == 1) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < RATE; i++) {
                                socket.send(sendPacket);
                                timer.cancel();
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < RATE; i++) {
                                socket.send(sendPacket);
                                timer.cancel();
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(rate, 0, 1000);
            readEchoPacket(socket);
        }

    }

    public static void readEchoPacket(DatagramSocket socket){

        try {

            /* Create datagram packet for receiving echoed message */
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

            socket.receive(receivePacket);

            String receivedEcho = new String(
                    receivePacket.getData(),
                    receivePacket.getOffset(),
                    receivePacket.getLength());

            receivedString.add(receivedEcho);

            /* Compares if the message is the same as the one that was sent */
            compareEchoMessage(receivedString);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    public static void compareEchoMessage(List<String> receivedMsg){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String str : receivedMsg) {
            sb.append(str);
        }
        System.out.println("Received: "+receivedMsg.toString());
        if (sb.toString().compareTo(MSG) == 0){
            System.out.printf("%s bytes sent and received!",sb.length());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("MESSAGE IS NOT EQUAL!");
        }
    }

    /* Splits the message equally */
    private static ArrayList<String> splitMessage(String message, int chunks)    {
        /* */
        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<>(
                (message.length() + chunks) - 1 / chunks);

        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += chunks){
            packages.add(message.substring(i, Math.min(message.length(),
                    i + chunks)));
        }
        return packages;
    }

    public static boolean isCorrect(String[] args) {

        /* Make sure all arguments are present */
        if (args.length != 4 && args.length == 0) {
            printUsage();
            return false;
        }
        else
            try {

                HOST_NAME = args[0];
                MY_PORT = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                MY_BUFFER = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                RATE = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

            /* Ensures RATE is not too high with a tested limit of 3000 */
                if (RATE > 3000) {
                    System.err.println("Rate value is too large!");
                    return false;
                }

            /* Make sure the host is valid */
                if (!isValidHost(HOST_NAME)) {
                    System.err.println("Host address is not valid!" +
                            "\nRequires a valid IP address or just localhost");
                    return false;
                }

             /* Make sure the port number is in the valid range */
                if (MY_PORT <= 0 || MY_PORT >= 65536) {
                    System.err.println("Port value must be in (0 -> 65535)!");
                    return false;
                }

            /* Make sure the buffer is at least 2, not lower */
                if (MY_BUFFER < 2){
                    System.err.println("Buffer must be higher or equal to 2!");
                    return false;
                }

            /* Split the message if bigger than buffer to appropriate packages */
                if (MSG.length() > MY_BUFFER) {
                    packages = (int) Math.ceil((double) MSG.length() / MY_BUFFER);
                    chars = (MSG.length() / packages);
                    originalMsg = splitMessage(MSG, chars);
                }

            /* Else adds whole message to array list */
                else {

                    packages = (int) Math.ceil( (double)MSG.length() / MY_BUFFER);
                    chars = (MSG.length() / packages);
                    originalMsg = splitMessage(MSG, chars);
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                printUsage();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                System.err.println("Invalid arguments!");
                printUsage();
                System.exit(1);
            }

        /* Everything is valid */
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidHost(String host) {

        /* Check if the string is valid */
        if (host == null || host.length() < 7 || host.length() > 15){
            return false;
        }
        else

        /* Host is valid "localhost" */
            if (host.equals("localhost")){
                return true;
            }

        /* Check the host string, should be in x.x.x.x format */
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(host,".");
        if (token.countTokens() != 4)
            return false;

        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {

            /* Get current token and convert to an integer value */
            String ip = token.nextToken();
            try {

                int ipVal = Integer.valueOf(ip).intValue();
                if ( ipVal < 0 || ipVal > 255)
                    return false;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /* IP Address looks valid */
        return true;
    }

    private static void printUsage() {
        System.err.println("Input arguments did not match expected arguments!" +
                "\nUsage: \"<host_name> <port> <message_buffer> <message_rate>\"");
    }
}
```

UDP Server:

```
/*
  UDPEchoServer.java
  A simple echo server with no error handling
*/
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class UDPEchoServer {
    public static final int BUFSIZE = 1024;
    public static final int MYPORT = 4950;
    public static boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];

        try{

            /* Create socket */
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);

            /* Create local bind point */
            SocketAddress localBindPoint = new InetSocketAddress(MYPORT);
            socket.bind(localBindPoint);

            System.out.println("---------------------------------"+
                    "\n| UDP Echo Server"+
                    "\n| Configuration: "+
                    "\n| port: "+MYPORT+
                    "\n---------------------------------");

            while (running) {

                /* Create datagram packet for receiving message */
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

                /* Receiving message */
                socket.receive(receivePacket);

                /* Create datagram packet for sending message */
                DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                        new DatagramPacket(receivePacket.getData(),
                                receivePacket.getLength(),
                                receivePacket.getAddress(),
                                receivePacket.getPort());

                String echo = new String(receivePacket.getData(),
                        receivePacket.getOffset(), receivePacket.getLength());

                System.out.printf("UDP echo request from %s", receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
                System.out.printf(" using port %d\n", receivePacket.getPort());
                System.out.println("Received: "+echo);

                 /* Send message*/
                socket.send(sendPacket);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException s){
            System.err.println(s.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect your output to be? On cursory look it seems to work well.

Comment: Yes it works really good when you have rate 1. I wrote wrong configuration string. i have updated the post now :

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what happens when your rate is 5:

This is the timer body:

```
                    if (RATE == 0 || RATE == 1) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < RATE; i++) {
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < RATE; i++) {
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
                        }

                    }
```

So, the `if` condition is `false`, because the rate is neither 0 nor 1. We go to the `else`:

```
                        for (int i = 0; i < RATE; i++) {
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
                        }
```

For `RATE` = 5, this is like writing:

```
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
                            socket.send(sendPacket);
                            timer.cancel();
```

Of course, cancelling the timer five times doesn't have any effect, but it *is* sending the same packet 5 times one-by-one. It will then send the next part 5 times, and the third part 5 times, because you are creating three separate timers for the parts.

I think if you want to send at a rate of 5 datagrams per second (is that the meaning of the `rate`?), you should not create as many timers as there are parts. You should create one timer, give it a list of datagrams to send, and set its schedule period to `1000L / rate` (make sure rate is not zero!). The timer should pop the next datagram from the list and send it. If there is no datagram left in the list, it should cancel itself.

- One loop to fill the list with datagrams
- Assign list to final variable which can be used from anonymous class, or to a field.
- Create timer and run it with `1000L / rate` schedule time.
- Run second loop for reading and comparing the received echo datagrams.

Note the two separate loops!

**About re-assembling the datagrams**

First, please note that the `DatagramPacket` that you receive from the server is not the same `DatagramPacket` that you sent to it *even if the contents are the same*! They are two different objects, and the `equals()` method from `Object` is not overridden, meaning that for any two objects `a` and `b` of type `DatagramPacket`, `a.equals(b)` is equivalent to `a == b`.

This means that the only thing you can compare is the datagram *content*, not the datagram *object*.

Since UDP does not guarantee that the packets will be sent in any particular order, you have to take care of this yourself. This usually means that you have to include more information in the datagram payload than just the string content. A good place to start is adding a byte that represents the number of the part.

For example, suppose you want to send the message "ABCDEF" in two packets containing "ABC" and "DEF". What you are doing now is sending something like:

```
┌──┬──┬──┐
│65│66│67│
└──┴──┴──┘
┌──┬──┬──┐
│68│69│70│
└──┴──┴──┘
```

Now you might get that back as

```
┌──┬──┬──┐
│68│69│70│
└──┴──┴──┘
┌──┬──┬──┐
│65│66│67│
└──┴──┴──┘
```

And you have no way to know that, and you'll re-assemble it and it will be `DEFABC`.

But if you sent another byte that gives the order:

```
┌─┬──┬──┬──┐
│0│65│66│67│
└─┴──┴──┴──┘
┌─┬──┬──┬──┐
│1│68│69│70│
└─┴──┴──┴──┘
```

you'd get the first byte, convert it to integer, and convert the rest of the bytes to string. Then you can put it in the list using the index, and they will come out in the proper order, no matter if you got the `1` packet first or second.

In a real world situation, you'll also send the size (number of packets) and an identifying number (so that if you get some rogue datagrams that belong to an old communication that only just arrived, they won't get mixed into your re-assembled payload.

Comment: Hmm okey. So if i understand 
1. Loop array list with message parts, and add the parts to a datagram packet and then in the same loop adds all the datagram packets to a datagram array list ?
? Then I'm not fully understands. What do you mean with 1000L/rate ?
I guess  don't need a for loop for the rate ? 
For the comparing, you mean basically this main idea? `for (DatagramPacket packet : datagrams)`

socket.send(packet);

compare the datagram each? 

send => compare => send => compare

Comment: 1. Create a List of datagrams. Loop on `originalMsg`, creating a datagram from each string and putting it in the list of datagrams. Then create a timer whose task pops a datagram from this list and sends it. It cancels itself if there are no more datagrams left in the list. A scheduled timer basically repeats until it is cancels, so there is no need for a loop inside the timer. Just pop one datagram and send it. Outside the timer, you need a second loop which calls your `readEchoPacket` method.

Comment: Ahaa. Okej i have done it so far. 
So in the timer task run() method i will only use for `(DatagramPacket datagram : datagramList){
socket.send(datagram);`

How do you mean i will read them ?
Can i still keep my re-assemble of the datagrams to a string builder ? 
The first part with sending them i think i am understanding but not how i should read them. Also should i use `timer.schedulerAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000)` ?

Comment: You should re-assemble them just as you do now, I suppose. Though theoretically, datagrams order is not guaranteed, so you might not get them in the same order that you sent them if you don't send along some indication of order. And no, as I said, the value should be `1000/RATE`, not `1000`. If you use `1000`, the task will be performed every second. If you want it to be performed four times per second, you need it to be performed every `1000/4` milliseconds.

Comment: Oh okey. Now i understand. Yeah the order of the msg part does not come in a constant order, so that re-assemble into a String is not a very smart idea if the rate isn't 1 msg/s or buffer is larger than msg.length().
But couldn't i compare the `datagramList` to a new datagramList that i place all the incoming packages from the server into ? So in theory i only compare the datagram packages, not the original string ? Really helpful so far i gotta say :D

Comment: @jabbeboy, I added some more information to my answer, as this is getting too long for a conversation in comments. I suggest you try to implement what I told you up till now, and re-think the way you want to assemble your datagram (based on your assignment, which you didn't detail). Perhaps your new code will be so different that it would be better to open a new question if you have more problems in it.